# iphone: Button/Image on top of TabBarController?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uitabbarcontroller

When in the Camera Roll section of the Photos app, you can click the top right button to edit the photos.  This replaces the bottom tab bar with three new buttons.

I would like to do something similar, but I cannot get my buttons to be on TOP of the tab bar.  Is there a way to specify the layer order?  Or do I need to do something different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a new UIView. I would add it to the view your tab bar is in (like, let's say UIWindow). From there you can use -bringViewToFront (or something similar). That way you will have control over what is in front of the UITabBarController's view.